# Finding the number of functions that can be formed.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, polynomials

Let $A$ is the set of first 7 natural numbers and $B$ is set of first 6 even natural numbers. Consider function $f:A\to B$ such that $f(x)\neq 2x$  $ \forall x\in A$ and $f(x)$ is an onto function. Find total number of functions that can be formed.

**My try**:

For a general $n$, let $A$ is the set of first $n$ natural numbers and $B$ is set of first $(n-1)$ even natural numbers.

Let $F_n$ be the number of such functions that can be formed.

Then using recursion I find that $$F_n=(!(n-1)) *(n-1)+ (n-1)F_{(n-1)}$$ and $F_2=0$ . Using this I can find $F_7$.

But I want to know if there is some other interesting method to work with such problems.  I specifically would like to use the **Rook Polynomials** but I am not able to do so in this question.  Any hints for this method and any other new methods are greatly appreciated

Comment: If $A = \{1, 2\}$ and $B = \{1\}$, then there is one surjective function from $A$ to $B$, namely the constant function that maps each element of $A$ to $1$.  Note that $f(x) \neq 2x~\forall x \in A$.  Hence, $F_2 = 1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig $B_n$ is the set of first $n-1$ *even* natural numbers.  I.e. it should be a function from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{2\}$.  $F_2=0$ is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz  You are correct.  I should have read the sentence more carefully.